# Using Google Sheet QUERY, how do I "SELECT / WHERE" mandatory and optional parameters over 2 tabs?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Search sheet searching for transactions through a Ledger sheet. The date is mandatory but all other parameters are optional. Problem being how to reference the optional parameter which is on the Search sheet and not in the Ledger sheet, i.e.
WHERE J not empty cell AND (J=A3) AND (C=C3 OR C3="") AND (F=F3 OR F3="")
(J, C, F is on Ledger sheet, A3, C3, F3 is on Search sheet)

QUERY(Ledger!A6:J, "Select J,B,C,D,E,F,G WHERE J is not null AND (J= '" & text(A3,"yyyy-MM-dd") & "' )  AND (...) AND (...)  ")

Here is my example, the date part is working:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vD-9IVc0bpPnNi3Bo85igYTtCbV9eP_3BjY3It2lPf0/edit#gid=1964422536
[SupplierLedgerSearch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKEdY.png)

Answer (score 0):

Because `QUERY()` treating first of of range `Ledger!A6:J` as header. So, use header parameter `0` to tell query function not to return header row. Try-

```
=QUERY(Ledger!A6:J, "Select J,B,C,D,E,F,G WHERE J is not null AND (J= '" & text(A3,"yyyy-MM-dd") & "' ) ",0)
```

***Reference:***
[QUERY Google Sheet function.](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en)

Comment: Not to be rude, but Google's funtion sheet is way outdated and incomplete.